# Near duplicate detection in Solr

Tags: php, solr, lucene, duplicates, dataimporthandler

Solr is being used to search through a database of user-generated listings. These listings are imported into Solr from MySQL via the DataImportHandler.

**Problem:** Quite often, users report the same listing to the database, sometimes with minor changes to their listing post to avoid being easily detected as a duplicate post.

How should I implement a near-duplication detection with Solr? I do not mind having near-duplicate listings in the Solr index as long as the search results do not contain these near-duplicate listings.

I guess there are 4 possible places to do this near-duplicate detection

1. When the user submits the listing *(PHP is being used here)*
2. During the data import from MySQL to Solr
3. After the data import from MySQL
4. When a search is being done

What is the recommended way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: In a pinch, you may use solr's "more like this" feature to flag stuff for reviewers, possibly step 3 of your workflow. It returns a coefficient that is 1.0 for a perfect match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm not familiar with Solr, i would implement the "near-duplication" when the user submits the listing. There are quit different algorithms to detect near-duplicates like the [Jaccard Indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_coefficient).

I made a little script to see the difference between the similarity coefficients:

```
<?php

$input1 = "Hello there, this is a test 1, you see it's almost the same";
$input2 = "Hello there, this is a test 2, you saw it, it's almost the same";
$input3 = "this is very different from the others, but who knows ?";

echo jackard($input1, $input1) . "<br />"; // results 1

echo jackard($input1, $input2) . "<br />"; // results 0.81481481481481

echo jackard($input1, $input3) . "<br />"; // results 0.25

echo jackard($input2, $input3); // results 0.24


function jackard($a, $b){
    $a_arr = explode(" ", $a);
    $b_arr = explode(" ", $b);
    $intersect_a_b = array_intersect($a_arr,$b_arr);
    return((count($intersect_a_b)/(count($a_arr)+count($b_arr)))*2);
}
?>
```

You may see, that if the result is 1, it means that it's the same sentence OR it uses the same words in a different order.
However, the smaller the value is, the more unique the "sentence" is. This is rather a simple implementation. You may set a limit value for example 0.4. And set the "request" in a queue if it passes this limit. And then take a look manualy at the listing. This is not "efficient". But i gave you the idea, and it's up to you to develop a more complex and automated system/algorithm. And maybe you should also take a look [here](http://phpir.com/shingling-near-duplicate-detection).

Comment: Thank you, this is an eye opener for me. If I want something like the near-duplicate detection of craigslist, do you see running every listing in the table (200,000 rows) through an algorithm like Jaccard's be a serious bottleneck with little processing power, like with only 4 cores on the server?

Comment: Euh well that's the problem, i tried some lorem ipsum text (5 sentences per variable), and tried a for loop 200.000 times, and it took about 20seconds on a quadcore 2.67Ghz (and this is without connecting to the database which makes the process slower)

Comment: I looked up a little and found Spotsig and LSH (Locality Sensitive Hashing) for near duplicate detection. Cant find any PHP libraries which can implement them. I wonder how Craigslist does it